# iOS 11 using vision framework VNDetectRectanglesRequest to do object detection not precisely?

Tags: ios, coreml, apple-vision

Apple have new features in iOS 11 that allows you use vision framework to do object detection without models. I try these new APIs but found **the result from VNDetectRectanglesRequest is not good. Am I using the APIs correctly?**

Here is some good case:

[image]

[image]

And some bad case:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
 func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
    guard let pixelBuffer: CVPixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer)

        // create the request

        let request2 = VNDetectRectanglesRequest { (request, error) in
            self.VNDetectRectanglesRequestCompletionBlock(request: request, error: error)
        }

        do {
            request2.minimumConfidence = 0.7
            try self.visionSequenceHandler.perform([request2], on: pixelBuffer)
        } catch {
            print("Throws: \(error)")
        }
    }


func VNDetectRectanglesRequestCompletionBlock(request: VNRequest, error: Error?) {
        if let array = request.results {
            if array.count > 0 {
                let ob = array.first as? VNRectangleObservation
                print("count: \(array.count)")
                print("fps: \(self.measureFPS())")
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    let boxRect = ob!.boundingBox
                    let transRect = self.transformRect(fromRect: boxRect, toViewRect: self.cameraLayer.frame)
                    var transformedRect = ob!.boundingBox
                    //transformedRect.origin.y = 1 - transformedRect.origin.y
                    let convertedRect = self.cameraLayer.layerRectConverted(fromMetadataOutputRect: transformedRect)

                    self.highlightView?.frame = convertedRect

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Are you asking about what cases this will succeed and fail under? That's going to be difficult to describe, because Apple's implementation of this is a black box and they could be using a number of different techniques to determine this. For example, your bottle example does not have clean, rectangular corners or straight edges, so if they were using corner or line detection it might not handle that case well.

Comment: I edit the question. I do not know exactly how to use the APIs correctly or the output boundingBox is just not good enough now

Comment: Using corelm to load tiny-yolo model will get better object detection than using vision framework so far

Comment: The built-in Vision operations are intended to be simpler detectors (template matching, shape detection), not generalized object detection like the YOLO network and related convolutional networks. They're solving different problems. Given that you're getting proper bounding boxes in cases where there are sharp edges and corners, and that they're not displaced by 90 degrees or something similar, you're probably using the API correctly. You just may be trying to use it for cases that these techniques don't handle well.

Comment: Got it, thank you for your comment :)

Comment: I am also facing the same issue, its getting highlight for non rectangle also. Please any one advise. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a lot of misconception, expectation, and black-box issues that have been brought up already. But aside from that, you’re also using the API incorrectly.

The rectangle detector finds areas in the image that appear to represent real-world rectangular shapes. In most cases, the camera capturing an image sees a real rectangular object in perspective — so its 3D projection onto the 2D image plane will usually not be rectangular. For example, the 2D projection of the computer screen in one of your photos is more trapezoidal, because the top corners are farther from the camera than the bottom corners.

You get this shape by looking at the actual corners of the detected    rectangle — see the properties of the [VNRectangleObservation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision/vnrectangleobservation) object. If you draw lines between those four corners, you’ll usually find something that better tracks the shape of a computer screen, piece of paper, etc in your photo.

The `boundingBox` property instead gets you the smallest rectangular area — that is, rectangular in image space — containing those corner points. So it won’t follow the shape of a real rectangular object unless your camera perspective is just right.

Answer (score 2):

Your commented out line is almost right, you need to put that back but change it to:

```
transformedRect.origin.y = 1 - (transformedRect.origin.y + transformedRect.width)
```

Your 'bad case' example the square is actually from the soft toy on the right.
Your good ones look right because they are in the centre of the screen.